# Why Omnis supervisor Queue Backlog shows cases that are assigned to users from queue

Tags: case, omnichannel, omni-supervisor

Our omni supervisor queue backlog shows cases that are assigned to user from queue.
It supposed to show only the cases owned by queue, not cases owned by users.

[image]

In the above picture TCAP Escalation is queue which is correct
But Gandy Flores is a user.

Anybody know the reason for this behavior.

Thank you,
Thiru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to delete PSR records  to resolve this issue.
Raise a case to Salesforce and they will delete the records for you.

Thank you,
Thiru